# What is the difference between a bug and a defect work item in TFS?

Tags: tfs, defects

I have just been asked to generate reports for TFS, and I noticed that there are both bug and defect reports.  Can anyone explain what the difference between the two is?

Comment: Some years ago, a Microsoft person told me that they do not have "bugs" at Microsoft; only *issues* :)

Answer (score 1):

The workitem types in TFS aren't hard coded. Every company can define their own workitems. So I guess your best choice is to ask the person who asked you to write the report. Maybe their "defect reports" is only for defect coffee machines? :)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly a defect is defined in the CMMI process template and is less specific than a bug ( as one defect could generate several bug items)

You would need to look at the template definition to see how the defect type is being used and ask how the defect type is being used for the project you are trying to create a report for.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same set-up in TFS.  I've been in testing for 20 years and only recently heard of a distinction between a bug and defect, and none of the explanations I've seen make any logical sense.

Bug and Defect get used interchangeably throughout the software industry.

My testing accreditation breaks these down into Error, Fault and Failure.  I've never had cause to use those distinctions but I can at least appreciate them.

In my new role I'm now being told that a bug is found in production and a defect found during development.  Other sites have referred to bugs being coding errors and defects being design-errors (or perhaps it was the other way round??).

IMO something can be defective for any number of reasons.  I won't be making the bug and defect distinction until someone's able to justify the value in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** A mistake in coding by development team is called error. It could be syntax error, semantic errors etc. *[This term is used by Developers]*

**Defect:** If something is developed against the requirement and is caught by testers during testing then it is called Defect. This term is also used for errors/mistakes found in post production.

**Bug:** If the code error reported by tester is accepted by development team then it is called Bug

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm gonna make this a short story rather than an article on '*What's a Bug and/or What's really a Defect*'.

**What is a Bug?**
A BUG is an error in the software that causes it to malfunction OR A BUG alters the behavior of the software and the software does not function as expected.

**What is a Defect?**
A DEFECT is a flaw in a product that reduces its usability or value OR If the feature does not work as per the user’s requirements, then it is termed as a DEFECT.

Simple, Isn't it?